# Padlock icon with iPhone frameworks in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode3.2

I'm getting a lot of linker errors (and missing architectures in i386), and I've noticed that my frameworks have got little white padlock items next to them... what does this mean? How can i solve the missing architecture error for UIKit and Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padlocks are normal All my framework icons have padlock badges as well. They just mean the files in the frameworks are not writable.

You will have padlocks on the API frameworks if you don't run with Admin permissions. I never do and never have problems with it.

Of course, if you have custom frameworks or the padlock badges suddenly appeared where none were before, you might have an issue. I would check for permissions problems.

You could check for a corrupted project by creating a new project with the same frameworks and seeing if the problem persist. Although, you should try a "clean all" before doing anything as that will get rid of most trivial linker problems.